# split record based on position in unix and compare the string with next record and copy

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

My input file is as below:

```
B0000001201012345519680415EN
B0000001201052323219921114
B0000001701233333319510802LN
B0000001701238999919460920
B0000000247974444419611219TN
B0000000246666666619910804
B0000000247777777719940329
```

I want to copy first record 'EN' to second record based on starting 9 bytes (`B00000012`).
The expected output is:

```
B0000001201012345519680415EN
B0000001201052323219921114EN
B0000001701233333319510802LN
B0000001701238999919460920LN
B0000000247974444419611219TN
B0000000246666666619910804TN
B0000000247777777719940329TN
```

I need to write this in unix shell scripting

Comment: good start with sample data and required output. But ... ;-) http://whatHaveYouTried.com ? Good luck.

Comment: It looks like you also want to append other values too.  Does B00000017 get LN and B0000024 get TN?

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -lape '$m = $1 if /([A-Z][A-Z])$/; s/(?<=[0-9]) *$/$m/' input
```

Output:

```
B0000001201012345519680415EN
B0000001201052323219921114EN
B0000001701233333319510802LN
B0000001701238999919460920LN
B0000000247974444419611219TN
B0000000246666666619910804TN
B0000000247777777719940329TN
```

Comment: this only handles the EN case.

Answer (score 1):

if you consider to do it with awk, this is a classical **FIELDWIDTHS** usage example:

```
awk -vFIELDWIDTHS="9 17 2" -vOFS="" '{if($1 in a)$3=a[$1];else a[$1]=$3}1' file
```

Comment: That's an interesting (but non-standard, as in 'not in POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)') extension — presumably it is found in GNU `awk` (it is not in Mac OS X / BSD `awk`, for example).

Comment: yes, gawk, I forgot mentioning about that..

Answer (score 1):

This would work with your input:

```
awk '!(x = substr($0,27)) { print $0 r; next } { r = x }1' file
```

However it would fail if a check of the first nine characters is required. To perform this check, try this:

```
awk 'x = substr($0,27) { a[substr($0,0,9)]=x } (y = substr($0,0,9)) in a && !x { print $0 a[y]; next }1' file
```

Results:

```
B0000001201012345519680415EN
B0000001201052323219921114EN
B0000001701233333319510802LN
B0000001701238999919460920LN
B0000000247974444419611219TN
B0000000246666666619910804TN
B0000000247777777719940329TN
```